# java convert pfx to a format that can be imported into default keystore

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, public-key-encryption

I am programatically loading a certificate into a default keystore with the following code

```
KeyStore kStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
java.io.FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keystorePath);
kStore.load(fis, new String(keystorePass).toCharArray());
fis.close();
```

I have a certificate from a third party in pfx format. If I try to load it, it fails with invalid format.

If I update to use the following it works. But I don't want to change the code.

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
```

How can I convert the pfx file to a format that will be accepted by the following

```
KeyStore kStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certificate stuff is never simple . You need openssl (the Cygwin version works on Windows) to convert the pfx / p12 file to a pem file, then you can create a certificate from the pem. Finally, you can use the Java `keytool` program to convert the certificate to JKS format (the KeyStore default).

Convert the pfx to pem:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in whatever.pfx -out whatever.pem -clcerts -nokeys
```

Create an X509 certificate from the pem file:

```
openssl x509 -in whatever.pem -inform PEM -out whatever.crt -outform DER
```

Use Java's keytool to create a JKS file from the cert:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore whatever.jks -storepass somepassword -noprompt -file whatever.crt -alias localhost
```

Note the `-alias` can be whatever unique name you want to use for this cert. The convention is to use the URL of your web site.

Now, you should be able to load the JKS file with the KeyStore instance in your code. Maybe it's easier to just change your Java code to use a PKCS12 instance?

Answer (score 0):

> If I update to use the following it works. But I don't want to change
>   the code.
>
> KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");   How can I
>   convert the pfx file to a format that will be accepted by the
>   following
>
> KeyStore kStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

Why not?
The default keystore format for Java is JKS.

But there are other formats and `#PKCS12` is the most frequently used.

If you need you application to be more "robust" I would recommend to not convert the file you have to the JKS format.

Instead you can support more than the JKS and e.g. try the default keystore type and if it fails try the `#PKCS12`

I would go further and suggest that the `KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());` is replaced by something like:

`KeyStore.getInstance(UserPreferences.getDefaultType());`

where the user has chose which should be the default keystore file (could be #PKCS12)